# Firebase keep track if is user authenticated

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to figure out how to keep a global state of my application whether the user is logged in or not. Do I have to have only one `onAuthStateChanged()` in my JavaScript file to keep track of state changed and add all HTML elements there like account details or is it a good idea to add multiple `onAuthStateChanged()` in each HTML file and have something like

```
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      document.getElementById("user-header-username").textContent = `Hi ${user.displayName}`;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("user-header-username").textContent = "Sign in";
    }
  }
```

I am very confused and cannot figure out how to structure my application in such an effective way to display specific parts if the user is logged and show something else if he is not and how to make it persistent throughout my application. I would appreciate if someone could explain how this process works in order to understand how to proceed.
I am using vanilla JavaScript for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to have only one onAuthStateChanged() in my JavaScript file to keep track of state changed and add all HTML elements there like account details or is it a good idea to add multiple onAuthStateChanged() in each HTML

You are going to need at least one auth state observer per loaded page in order for each page to be able to access the current user.  That's normal.

If you need multiple observers per page for whatever reason, that's fine as well.  It's up to you to decide what code best meets your app's needs.

The main point of the observer is to notify you when a user is known to be signed in (which doesn't happen immediately on page load).  It will also tell you if the user becomes signed out.  What you do with those events is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of application state.

I suggest you redux: https://redux.js.org/

With Redux your code would look something like this (pseudo code):

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
      store.dispatch("user-logged-in", user)
    } else {
      store.dispatch("user-logged-out")
    }
  }

store.subscribe("user-logged-in", (user) => {
  document.getElementById("user-header-username").textContent = `Hi ${user.displayName}`;
  // other side effects
})

store.subscribe("user-logged-out", () => {
  document.getElementById("user-header-username").textContent = "Sign in";
  // other side effects
})
```